# Responsive menu icon issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have an issue. I have a menu but I want to make it responsive with a button click ( font awesome) when i set display:none; and then display:block on the media query , my icon doesn't appear.. pls help.

html:

```
<div id="menuIcon">
                       <i class="fa fa-bars fa-3x" style="color:white"></i>
  </div>
```

css:

```
@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:640px){
   .menuRight{
       display:none;
   }

   #menuIcon{
       display:block;
       float:right;
       cursor:pointer;
   }
}

#menuIcon{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your above code, the display:none; is below the display:block; so it is overriding it. Organize your code like this and it will work:

```
#menuIcon{
    display:none;
} 

@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:640px){
   .menuRight{
   display:none;
 }

 #menuIcon{
   display:block;
   float:right;
   cursor:pointer;
 }
}
```

Also, see this on cascading: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just try to set `display: block;` as `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

If you add style to an element twice in your CSS file, CSS gives higher priority to the code added at the last.

e.g.

```
.box { color: #fff; }
.box { color: #000; }
```

The property of **.box** will be **color: #000;** since it was added at the last.

Just change your code to the following:

```
#menuIcon{
    display:none;
}

@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:640px){
   .menuRight{
       display:none;
   }

   #menuIcon{
       display:block;
       float:right;
       cursor:pointer;
   }
}
```